# Как сделать авторизацию в yii2 с помощью dektrium?

Tags: yii2, vkontakte-api

Я по этой ссылке https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user установил и решил использовть. Короче мне надо авторизация через соц сети, а именно через вк. По этой ссылке https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/... указали как реализовать, я все сделал но одно не понимаю, не там дальше инструкции что сделать. Как мне дальше на вюжку выводить кнопку "войти с помощью ВК"? как дальше реализовать помогите с решением пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам нужно использовать адрес - `/user/registration/connect`

Подробнее тут:

https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/7178050b17e65777e21421993842647a038e5b0a/controllers/RegistrationController.php#L152

https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/views/registration/connect.php